# Do 50 Ω signal generators have a series resistor or not?

Tags: rf, impedance, transmission-line, function-generator

I am wondering about something really simple and silly.

If functions generators have an internal series 50 Ω termination, then they would produce only half the set amplitude over a matched load.

However, if they instead had a low impedance driver, they would produce the full requested amplitude over a matched load, which sounds like a more intuitive (too me) design.

So do they have this series resistor R1 and if yes, what is the motivation behind it ?

[image]

Comment: A **function generator** failing to follow a voltage source with a real 50 ohm resistor isn't worth its salt. But the term *function generator* might be used loosely - where does this term morph into *RF generator* ? One might get a clue looking at how output amplitude is specified - an *RF generator* might talk about dBm output. I might install a 50-ohm attenuator to such a generator's output to better-ensure a 50-ohm output Z.

Comment: @glen_geek So does that mean that power amplifiers don't have the resistor and expect a matched load *only*?

Comment: tobalt - most likely. I'd hope a power amplifier might also spec output VSWR. Any "gain" spec (expressed as dB) would likely be offered with proviso: *50 ohm source & load*...that is: *insertion gain*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *do they have this series resistor R1 and if yes, what is the
> motivation behind it*

Signal generators that are specified as having an output impedance of 50 Ω have a 50 Ω output resistor and, when loaded with 50 Ω the open circuit terminal voltage drops to half.

The motivation is to prevent reflections and "guarantee" an output impedance that can be relied upon even when the output is shorted i.e. 1 volt open circuit will produce 20 mA on the shorted output.

> *However, if they instead had a low impedance driver, they would
> produce the full requested amplitude over a matched load, which sounds
> like a more intuitive (too me) design.*

Some signal generators do have the option for bypassing the series output resistor.

Answer (score 13):

More precisely, they have whatever impedance makes up the difference.  Or, they should, anyway.

For example, my old Wavetek 193 has a discrete (complementary emitter follower, more or less) output stage, which has a low impedance, so there's about 50 ohms in series after it.  The switchable attenuators need this (stable) impedance as well, of course, and in turn present the same impedance after.

Presumably, one could construct an output stage with a mix of current and voltage feedback, so that the output impedance is 50 ohms by design, without having to waste power in a series resistor (*or a shunt resistor for current source drivers!*).  The difficulty here is, to get the right mix of negative feedback, and in particular to sense output current, probably some weird feedback networks (perhaps as messy as a current-sense amp) might be needed, and these will have significant phase shift at high frequencies, plus the voltage and current paths may not match, *plus* the overall frequency response itself will be dropping with frequency due to limited gain bandwidth.  So it's not an easy task, making a fast amplifier, that is also low distortion and flat response, and flat impedance.

So, most just take the brute-force way out, and add the load resistor.  Easy enough.

Note that many RF circuits may not use a follower (or can't because it kind of doesn't exist, at the highest frequencies), in which case they use a common-emitter/source stage instead, and the output is Norton equivalent rather than Thevenin.  In this case, output current is wasted (rather than output voltage), and the resistor is in shunt with the output, not series.  The two cases are equivalent, of course, so we don't notice, or care.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd use an stronger word than "presumably" when it comes to double loop feedback designs for accurate output/input impedance matching, it's tough, but the rewards are many. 
There are designs (and I know of, at least, one designer) who use double loop to produce an accurate input or output impedance for custom designs. It is unfortunate that they are not so talked about in the mainstream literature. The only source I know where they have been properly classified is in Ernst Nordholt's thesis from 1980.

Answer (score 9):

They should act as if they do.

An ideal 50Ω output impedance output should produce the requested output into a 50Ω load. A good test of how ideal it is is whether it produces double the voltage into an open circuit, and double the current into a short circuit.

Many RF generators are implemented as a voltage source *at the generated output frequency* followed by a discrete 50Ω resistor. The voltage source is implemented as level-controlling feedback, usually through a power sensor. The controlling action of the feedback loop sets the voltage at the output of the voltage source, creating a zero output impedance. This arrangement is not neccesarily as wasteful as it seems, as the amplifier only has to drive a 100Ω load, rather than 50Ω.

As such, they usually do not have a 50Ω output impedance at other frequencies. If measured with an output incident frequency that is far removed from the generated frequency, then the beat frequency doesn't affect the feedback loop. If it's close, then the loop gets modulated, and the output can generate some nasty intermodulation distortion.

This voltage source + a real 50Ω resistor requires double the voltage headroom over what would be needed for a native 50Ω output amplifier. Some generators use current as well as voltage feedback to synthesise a finite output impedance from their amplifier, which is then followed with a less than 50Ω resistor, wasting less energy - or alternatively allowing a higher output power to be specified for the same amplifier components.

Answer (score 6):

They do.

Just measure any standard signal generator into no load and into 50 ohm load, and you will see the amplitude drop to half.

They compensate for that by having a menu to select if the amplitude shown to the user is the terminated or unterminated amplitude.

The motivation to have 50 ohm source impedance is not only one. It is used as obvious source termination for driving 50 ohm coax cables, which also absorbs any reflections coming back from the load, offers some short circuit protection and isolates the driver from driving capacitive loads directly.

So if it did not have a 50 ohm resistor, it would not be a signal source with 50 ohm impedance, intended to be used with other equipment and cables which are intended to have 50 ohm impedance.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the motivation for adding it in the first place? The low impedance driver would transfer 4x as much power in the load and waste less in the generator itself according to my simulations.

Comment: @tobalt when you study transmission line theory, you'll see the motivation.